# How to open an application as  an administrator from command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, cmd

Opening an application( probably an .exe file) as an administrator in headless mode from command prompt

Comment: what about launching the cmd as an administrator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true):

```
runas /user:Administrator program
```

It will ask for the Administrator's password.